# IE loads incomplete assets (Vue Javascripts, stylesheets)

Tags: css, apache, webpack, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I build a web app using Vue.js2 and Sass packed with webpack, transpiled with Babel. The backend is build with PHP framework Symfony2.

I have full support for browsers based on webkit - Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge, however, I did everything to make sure it's compatible with IE11, I have some issues on production and testing env (both run under **apache2**). **CSS are autoprefixed** by webpack plugin and PostCSS.

While I run the server locally using PHP built-in server, everything works perfectly. While I launch the app from server with apache, in Webkit browsers, everything works perfectly as well. Now the interesting part is, IE 11 is not able to load complete asset files. CSS are broken and barely half of the page is styled up. Also the Javascripts are incomplete, that causes missing fc declaration and nothing is rendered due to errors.

This occurs only in IE11. We have F5 firewall on production, also internal proxy in our company's network. But since the problem is only IE11 related, I don't think the problem lays there.

Do you have any idea, where's the problem? Can apache modify headers to be incompatible with IE11?

Comment: what are the errors you got in IE? It is possible that issue caused by autoprefix webpack plugin or postcss. It is also possible that your site taking much time to load so IE close the connection and files load incompletely. It is very broad topic. I have find that IE 10 had this kind of issue with Apache. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/26/https-and-keep-alive-connections/ not sure, whether this is the same issue. We need some more information to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly I am not sure if it's related to any of code modifications for IE, because everything run at local server, the problem is with apache hosted app.

Anyways the problem is:
SCRIPT1010 - related to JS
Also there is a warning:
DOM7011

Anyways, this problems occurs exlusively on IE11 (previous versions are not supported at all)

Comment: Also notice, that styles does not throw any errors at all. IE looks like everything is loaded.